# What is an effective way to teach my dog "paw"?

Tags: dogs, training

My 5 month old pitbull has been doing fairly well with learning some tricks such as "sit" and "lay down."  However, I can't seem to get her to learn "paw."  Whenever I try to teach her using treats as a reward, she focuses primarily on the treat and nothing else.  She will stare at the treat and ignore my command.  If I put the threat in my hand with a closed fist, and use my other hand to demonstrate I want her paw, she will sniff and lick my hand, likely looking for the treat I just had in it.

Is there a better way to teach this? The usual technique of giving her a treat when she does it correctly isn't working for me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the other way around for a while.

When she doesn't obey the command, hold her paw up and clearly reinforce the command "Paw" while you hold her paw.  Then give the treat.

Repeat this over the next few days and she should start associating the command with the action and perform "Paw" pro-actively in order to get the treat.